# how do we get the first and last day of the current month

Tags: salesforce, apex-code

How do we get the first day of the month and last day of the month. i am using it on a apex class.

i can get the todays date by using

```
date.today()
```

but how would i get the first and last day of the month.

Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should get familiar with the [Apex Code Developers Guide](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/index.htm) as it has very good documentation for questions like this. Here's the [Date methods page](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_date.htm) that you would find helpful.

With respect to your specific question, you get the first date of the month (I'll use today's month in my example) using the following

`Date firstDayOfMonth = System.today().toStartOfMonth();`

To get the last day of the month, use the following:

`Date lastDayOfMonth = firstDayOfMonth.addDays(Date.daysInMonth(firstDayOfMonth.year(), firstDayOfMonth.month()) - 1);`

Answer (score 1):

I think there is a better way to solve  the second problem, that is, accept the last day of the month.

```
firstDayOfMonth.addMonths(1).addDays(-1);
```